# Can't turn keyboard's light in Zorin Os (Linux)

Tags: linux, keyboard, zorin

I've installed Zorin OS because i saw a video, recommending it for new Linux Users, but when i boot Zorin OS, the key that turns on and off keyboard's light doesn't make any difference, it doesn't work.

Every time i boot Zorin OS, I have to open terminal and write `xset led 3`, that turns on the keyboard's light manually, but it's a bit annoying because I have to do it each time i boot Zorin OS.

My PC Specs:

- Motherboard: Gygabyte M68MT-S2 with Socket AM3+
- Memory: Kingston Hyper X 2x 4Gb.
- Micro: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six Core Processor
- Keyboard: GTC Ribbon KGG-002

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Which light? NumLock? CapsLock? ScrollLock? Keyboard backlight? Something else? Please click [edit] and update your question. It would also be helpful to know the make and model of your PC and keyboard; please get the make and model from the serial number plate, as any number on the topside is likely a Marketing Model and useless in finding tech manuals. Please do _not_ click [Add Comment] as comments get pushed off the page when multiple comments pile up.

Comment: It sounds like the keyboard has a backlight.  That's an enhanced feature that isn't part of the standard keyboard interface; it's likely controlled by an OEM driver.  You can search for a Linux version of the driver.  But if that's the only feature not being supported and you can fix it with a command, there's a simple solution.  Save the command as a script and have that script run at startup.  That's typically accessible in System Settings.  Or see options described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13886/how-to-light-up-back-lit-keyboard